# Finding out Expected Value

Tags: probability

After being all out for 58 and 78 in two matches in the most prestigious tournament in the world, the coach of a certain national cricket team was very upset. He decided to make the batsmen practice a lot.

But he was wondering how to make them practice, because the possibility of getting out seems completely random for them. So, he decided to keep them in practice as long as he can and told them to practice in the net until a batsman remains not-out for k consecutive balls.Now the coach is wondering how many balls the practice session is expected to take.

For a batsman the probability of being out in a ball is independent and is equal to p. What is the expected number of balls he must face to remain not out for k consecutive balls?
If the value of p and k is given how can I find out the the expected number of balls he must face to remain not out for k consecutive balls.
I'm a novice in learning expected value so better explanation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

p => success

q => failure

Let $X_k =$ number of balls needed to obtain first k consecutive notouts.

Problem:  Finding $E_k = E(X_k)$

For $k = 1$ Number of balls required for 1 notout.

$E(X_1 = k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}$

$E(X_1) = \frac{1}{p}$

$E_k = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} +\cdots \frac{1}{p^k}$

$E(x) = \sum_{y} E(X/Y=y)Pr(y)$

$X = X_k =$number of balls needed to obtain first run of k consecutive notouts in a row.

$Y =$ ball after the first run of k-1 notouts in a row.

$E_k = p\left(E_{k-1} +1\right) + (1-p)\left(E_{k-1}+1+E_k\right)$

$E_k = \frac{1}{p}E_{k-1} + \frac{1}{p}$

By Induction,

we get $E_k = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} +\cdot \frac{1}{p^k}$

That is the expected number of ball that he has to play for him to survive k consecutive balls.